# Aptana Ruby on Rails Problem, rails: command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aptana

I installed Aptana Studio 3 and attempted to create my first Rails file, only to receive the error

```
sh.exe: rails: command not found
```

Am I supposed to edit my System Variables to include the Path? If so, where the heck is rails.exe because I cannot find that directory.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your "sh.exe" filename, I am assuming you are running Windows. You will need to verify that the command "rails" is accessible in your system path so that Aptana can find it. Do this by modifying the "PATH" system variable to include the directory to your Ruby installation (this may require a restart to take affect).

Instructions for modifying the system path can be found here: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

If you used an installer of Ruby packaged for Windows such as Railsinstaller, point to the path of this installation. Gems will place executable files in the "\bin" folder. The "rails" executable is a script from the rails gem.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem and I have solved it. I am using Windows 7 with Aptana Studio 3. The problem is that actually Rails is not installed on my Computer after I installed Aptana Studio 3.

Basically I follow the instructions given by [this website](http://rubyonrails.org/download)

First you need a ruby installer for windows. After installation, Click on `Start Command Prompt with Ruby` from `Start->All program->ruby` folder and type `gem install rails` in command line and you are done. Wish that you can solve your problem as well.

Answer (score 2):

Aptana Studio 3 does not install rails for you by default.  You will need to download a rails installer as mentioned here:

http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Rails+Development